# How to Sum value of fields in a ms access form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form where in need to calculate sum of multiple text boxes.
example:  i have two text boxes A=10.15 and B= 15.60. I want to sum their values in text box 'c'. I tried using the sum function but results in '#Error' and '+' which appends the two values '10.1515.60'.

Any Suggestions???
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Tried this `=Val[TextBoxA.value]+Val[TextBoxB.value]`

it works, when I try to sum two textboxes in another textbox, at first Access concatenated the values but with this formula access let you sum both values.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Control Source of textbox C (without the quotes).

```
'=[TextBoxA]+[TextBoxB]'
```

Make sure the textbox format is Number. Leaving it blank concatenates the values.

Comment: tried this option too. I'm still getting concatenated values

Comment: What is the format of your textboxes? Set it to Standard with 2 decimal places and test.

Answer (score 0):

The SUM function is for totaling the values in the same field, across multiple records.

To calculate the total of two textboxes, set the Control Source property of textbox C to the following (include the = sign)

= NZ([A],0) + NZ([B],0)

The NZ function gracefully handles NULLS by changing them to 0.

Note that textbox C will be unbound, so the sum will not be stored in your table (but it is not a good practice to store calculations, so that should be OK).

Comment: Tried it. But does not work. It is still appending values

Comment: In the table design, make sure that the field is defined as a number and that it's Length property is set to "Double".